# How to type Malayalam in Ubuntu?

Tags: input-language, malayalam

Is it possible to type Malayalam language in Ubuntu? If yes, what should I do to type Malayalam in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Install ibus first.

   ```
    sudo apt-get install ibus
   ```

   or click [this](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/ibus).
2. Install the m17n library which holds the indic fonts (includes good old malayalam).

   ```
    sudo apt-get install ibus-m17n m17n-contrib
   ```

   or click [this](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/ibus-m17n) then [this](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/m17n-contrib).
3. Go to **System** ▸ **Preferences** ▸ **Ibus preferences**
4. Take the 'input method' tab.
5. From the drop down menu *Select an input method*, choose **malayalam** ▸ **swanalekha** and then click on <kbd>Add</kbd>.
6. Open up a text editor, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> (or <kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>) to change the language and type away.

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu 16.04 this was what I did. It looks like ibus is already installed, not sure if that is same for all.

Go to *System Settings* -> *Text Entry*.

From the input source to use, click on the <kbd>+</kbd> button and add your languages. Once you add you can click on the language and choose any specific font you need. Eg: I was going for the recent one [Manjari](https://blog.smc.org.in/manjari-font/).

To test press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key (<kbd>Super</kbd>) + <kbd>Space</kbd> (if you have configured different one use that). You can switch to other fonts. Hope that helps someone.