# How I can type in the Malayalam language?

Tags: ibus, input-language

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to type Malayalam in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142977/how-to-type-malayalam-in-ubuntu)

How I can type Malayalam language in Ubuntu 12.10? I used to use ibus with m17n library on my Ubuntu 12.04. But after a fresh installation of 12.10, m17n is no more available on ibus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try to update the repository indexes? 
Its seems that `ibus-m17` is now available for `Quantal`. To update use `sudo apt-get update` and then try to install the `ibus-m17n` package by using `sudo apt-get install ibus-m17n`.
IF you're still unable to install the package, then manually download the package from the following link, and install it:

- http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/ibus-m17n

Comment: @Scorp, You're welcome. So did you do it manually or did the index update do the trick for you?

Comment: after index update I  reinstalled m17n  again and now ibus  works  perfectly..