# Need Google Input Tools to type Telugu in Celtx

Tags: language-support, input-language, input-method

I need Google Input Tools for writing scripts in Telugu language in Celtx in Ubuntu 13.10. I tried various methods, but none is as simple as Google Input Tools. Is there a way?

Comment: What's the output of running `sudo apt-get install ibus-m17n
`??

Comment: _Celtx is really a web application. We have the advantage of big computers on the web doing stuff for us instead of having to depend on the much more limited resources of our local machine._ Source: Celtx: Open Source Screenwriting
Beginner's Guide.

Answer (score 10):

First install Chromium Web Browser, and after that install the Google Input Tools extension for Google Chrome (it also works in Chromium). Google Input Tools lets you type in the language of your choice in Google Chrome and Chromium web browsers.

You can try Google Input Tools in your web browser before you install it at [Try Google Input Tools online](https://www.google.com/inputtools/try/). To try it out, choose your language and input tool from the dropdown menus and begin typing.

**Install Chromium Web Browser**

1. Chromium Web Browser is the open source version of Google Chrome. Open the Ubuntu Software Center and search for *chromium-browser*.
2. Select **Chromium Web Browser** and click on the button that says **Install**
3. Authenticate with your user password to install Chromium Web Browser.

**Install Google Input Tools extension for Google Chrome**

1. Open Chromium Web Browser.
2. Visit the [Google Input Tools extension for Google Chrome webpage](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-input-tools-by-goo/mclkkofklkfljcocdinagocijmpgbhab?hl=en).
3. Click the blue button that says **+ FREE** to add the Google Input Tools extension to Chromium Web Browser.

If you used Google Input Tools to type in Asian languages when using Microsoft Windows, you might wonder how to do it in Ubuntu applications. See this question: [How do I enable writing in Indian languages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165637/how-do-i-enable-writing-in-indian-languages).

For using the Malayalam language in Ubuntu applications see [How to type Malayalam in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142977/).

Comment: i have performed what you said but i see an error. gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.